# Extract line number with checkbox

Tags: livecode

how can i extract line with check box. In my stuck i have 
text fld: "news", 
group of checkbox: "Checkboxs", 
checkbox: "Check 1 - Check 10", 
button: "button" and a destination fld "Lower".

Now i went:

1) when i select multiple checkbox, checkbox will extract multiple line form text fld "news".

2) when i press button, button get text from fld "news" through checkbox and put it to fld "lower" horizontally one by one.
I have upload my project [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gexsnnxzxqqvecu/test.livecode?dl=0) you may check it.
Plz advice.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like:

```
on mouseUp
   local tLower, tNews, tLineNumber
   put field "news" into tNews
   repeat for each line tID in the childControlIDs of group "Checkboxs"
      -- checkboxes named "Check <linenumber>"
      put word 2 of the short name of control id tID into tLineNumber
      put line tLineNumber of tNews & return after tLower
   end repeat
   delete the last char of tLower
   put tLower into field "lower"
end mouseUp
```

Comment: button "Button": execution error at line 4 (Chunk: can't find background), char 32. plz advice

Comment: also i am not clear line 5 (-- checkboxes named "Check <linenumber>"). should i put checkbox name and call line number individually? plz advice

Comment: Execution error at line 4 will happen if the name of the group does not match what is used in the script.

Comment: Line 5 is a comment. Valid line comment symbols in LiveCode are -- and #. Block comments are /* comment here */.

Comment: Hi, your post said you had a group named `Checkboxs` so I guess that's not true. I presumed where you said `checkbox "Check 1 - Check 10"` it meant that you had 10 checkboxes named `Check 1`, `Check 2` etc corresponding to the line number  of `field "news"` you want included in `field "lower"`